# WAR file Deployement failed with 'Illegal state exception' on tomcat while using SOAPWebserviceTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

When i'm trying to deploy the proj.War file which is built with spring boot, tomcat server gives the IllegalStateException for spring transaction manager class.

Here are the Details:
Java :11.0.3
Tomcat:9
SpringBoot
Spring-Web-services(SOAP).

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child

              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:716)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)

              at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

              at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

              at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

              at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:934)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)

              at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

              at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

              at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637)

              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

              at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)

              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/proj]]

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)

              ... 37 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.restTemplateBuilder

              at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)

              at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)

              at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)

              at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)

              at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)

              at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)

              at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)

              at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)

              at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)

              at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)

              at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)

              at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)

              at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)

              at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)

              at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)

              at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)

              at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)

              at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)

              at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)

              at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)

              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5120)

              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

              ... 38 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader

  context: proj

  delegate: false

Parent Classloader:

java.net.URLClassLoader@35d176f7

]

              at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)

              at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)

              at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742)

              at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:741)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:648)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1614)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:495)

              at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238)

              at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231)

              at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221)

              at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169)

              at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144)

              at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)

              ... 59 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/ReactiveTransactionManager

              at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

              at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)

              at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)

              at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)

              ... 75 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.ReactiveTransactionManager

              at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1343)

              at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1173)

              ... 79 more
```

Comment: Apparently you have included something that triggers reactive stuff which needs the `org/springframework/transaction/ReactiveTransactionManager` class. Also does it not start or logs this at the info level?

Comment: I believe you are using spring transaction-related class or annotation in some of your work. So you need to add spring-tx dependencies in your project